# Without G Suite account set up. Can I post the data on google plus page using google client API PHP

Tags: php

I need to post some data on my google plus page using google client API. 
I have logged in my google business account through google client API.

```
I have got below error "https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/people/me/activities: (403) Forbidden".
```

I have searched a lot of time how to fix this issue . Some body posted we need "G Suite" account . So how Can I create a G suite account for my existing domain.or  without G suite account,what are the scopes needed to post data on google plus page using google client api